# tortoisesvn: howto use key authentication rather than password?

Tags: authentication, tortoisesvn

I have tortoiseSVN set up on my local windows 7 computer.  I access the repository with a password.  For example, if I right-click on a file from within Windows Explorer, and then select 'repo-browser', the password dialogue box pops up.

I now would like to modify my setup to use key authentication, rather than passwords.  I followed the instructions here:  http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ssh-create-keys.html

Everything worked fine until I got to this step:

> > Testing SSH with TortoiseSVN: ... Right click on any folder in Windows
> >     Explorer and select TortoiseSVN →
> >     Repo-Browser. You will be prompted to
> >     enter a URL, so enter one in this
> >     form:
>
> svn+ssh://svnuser@SvnConnection/repos

When I select Repo-Browser, the password dialogue pops up immediately.  I am not prompted to enter a URL.  If I try canceling the password dialogue, the password dialogue just pops up again.

How do I get the password dialogue to stop popping up?  How do I "tell" TortoiseSVN that I want to use key authentication rather than passwords?

Answer (score 1):

The password dialog probably pops up because TorToiseSVN fails to find any ssh key.

On Windows, this is usually due to the environment variable **`HOME`** being *not* defined by default. (`HOMEDIR` is, `HOME` is not).

You can set `HOME` to any directory of your choice, it needs to contain a .ssh directory with your public/private key in it.
Then, make sure that [basic SSH communication works first](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ssh-test-putty.html), before fiddling with the TortoiseSVN client itself.

Comment: Question:  I am unable to create a ".ssh" directory.  It seems that under Windows 7, a directory name cannot begin with a period.  Help?

Comment: I know this is old, but to create folders that begin with a '.' just use mkdir from the command prompt.

Comment: @user606696 as Robin says, use `mkdir`: see his comment